# Rails Capistrano with wrong rbenv path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I tried to use **Capistrano** on rails app.
but I faced some problem: when I run `cap production deploy:check`, it seems ok

only wrong messages: does it matter?

```
DEBUG [a8c55ce2] Command: /usr/bin/env which passenger
DEBUG [a8c55ce2] Finished in 0.004 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).)
```

but when I run `cap production deploy`, get messages:

> DEBUG [a71a7cfc]  bash: /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv: No such file or
>   directory

and I search my server, I have no /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv. but I have `/usr/local/rbenv` and I can use rails and deploy website for rails app, how can I find the right path on `/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv`? or it is another problem?

here is my setting:

```
lock '3.4.0'

`ssh-add` # need this to make key-forwarding work

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'my ssh'

set :deploy_to, '/home/john/projects/myapp'
set :log_level, :debug
set :keep_releases, 5
set :linked_files, %w(config/database.yml config/secrets.yml)
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push("bin", "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system") 

set :rbenv_type, :user 
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.2.2"
set :rbenv_path, "/usr/local/rbenv"
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w(rake gem bundle ruby rails)
set :rbenv_roles, :all 

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
        execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
    end
  end
end
```

My folder

```
john@ip:/usr/local/rbenv$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 john admin 4096 Aug  5 16:44 shims
-rw-r--r-- 1 john admin    6 Aug  4 15:40 version
drwxr-xr-x 3 john admin 4096 Aug  4 15:33 versions
```

and I find 3 possible path with my plugin:

```
/home/john/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
/home/john/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
/home/john/.rbenv/bin
```

I think it's my installization rbenv problem to cause this path problem.

Comment: Please run `cd /usr/local/rbenv && ls -l` and add its output to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure to include and configure correctly the [capistrano-rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/) gem

In your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
end
```

In your Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
```

Set the rbenv related variables in your config/deploy.rb:

```
# I assume your plugins directory is at /usr/local/rbenv/plugins
#    shims directory at /usr/local/rbenv/shims
#    and so on ... Adapt the following to your situation

set :default_env, {
    path: '/usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH',
    rbenv_root: '/usr/local/rbenv'
}
set :rbenv_roles, :all
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.2'
set :rbenv_ruby_dir, '/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2'
set :rbenv_custom_path, '/usr/local/rbenv'
```

Comment: shims directory at /usr/local/rbenv/shims, this path is right! but /usr/local/rbenv/plugins is wrong? does anyway I can find the path in my Server(ubuntu)? I use find /plugins/ and shows
find: `/plugins/': No such file or directory. and my Gemfile and Capfile is OK.

Comment: you just need to adapt to your configuration and set the path that correspond to your server